# How to compile kotlin native code into an iOS framework?

Tags: kotlin, shared-libraries, cross-platform, kotlin-native

from [Kotlin Native 0.5](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/12/kotlinnative-v0-5-released-calling-kotlin-from-swift-and-c-llvm-5-and-more/), we can compile the kotlin code into a `framework` for integrating into an existing iOS project.

I just wonder how to do it?

**What I want**

1. Using command line to build
2. Build from the [kotlin native repo](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native) so that I can catch up with the latest update.
3. Without using Gradle so that I don't need to do a gradle project setup.

I know there is a `calculator` sample in the `samples` folder, and it adds an extra step called `Compile Kotlin framework` in the `Xcode` project to do the magic. But I don't know how to separate that step.

I tried using command line like this: `../../dist/bin/kotlinc ./src/main/kotlin/org/konan/arithmeticparser/Parser.kt -produce framework -o asd.framework`.

But the result has a different structure compare to the gradle build one.

Any help here? Thanks

Comment: In case some one has the issue, I have a blog for it: http://www.albertgao.xyz/2018/01/14/how-to-create-kotlin-native-ios-project/

Comment: see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596110/kotlin-file-in-native-ios-project-with-kotlin-native

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "different structure"? Kotlin/Native gradle plugin and CLI tools flags are processed by the same code, so if you pass identical options - result is identical as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this tutorial [here](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-seamlessly-share-code-between-ios-and-android-using-kotlin). Although it uses gradle, but it basically includes a script that automatically rebuilds the kotlin framework for ios. Im not sure this is what you require, but you can write a shell script on the same principles.

```
task lipo(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'build') {
def frameworks = files(
        "$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone/${frameworkName}.framework/$frameworkName",
        "$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone_sim/${frameworkName}.framework/$frameworkName"
)
def output = file("$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone_universal/${frameworkName}.framework/$frameworkName")
inputs.files frameworks
outputs.file output
executable = 'lipo'
args = frameworks.files
args += ['-create', '-output', output]
}
task copyFramework(type: Copy, dependsOn: lipo) {
    from("$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone") {
        include '*/Headers/*'
        include '*/Modules/*'
        include '*/Info.plist'
}
from "$buildDir/konan/bin/iphone_universal"
into "${rootProject.rootDir}/ios"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another tutorial is here 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/apple-framework.html
You may probably use Gradle as the build system, see https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/GRADLE_PLUGIN.md