# How to package kotlin native library so it can be used in android and iOS projects?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, aar, ios-frameworks

I would like to develop api calls (networking) in kotlin (native) and use the same code/lib in android and iOS project.
I plan to use this lib:
https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel

Is this possible? 
How to build iOS framework and android lib (aar) from the same kotlin code?
Which IDE/tools are the best for creation of libs for both platforms?

Comment: https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/multiplatform-native-development-in-kotlin-now-with-ios-a8546f436eec

Comment: I dont want to develop ios app in Kotlin. I would like to use swift and call functions from kotlin lib.

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/12/kotlinnative-v0-5-released-calling-kotlin-from-swift-and-c-llvm-5-and-more/

Comment: So the trick for ios is using kotlinc with -produce framework switch. Is there support for this in intelij IDE, so i can output android and ios libs from there?

Comment: see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596110/kotlin-file-in-native-ios-project-with-kotlin-native

Comment: Harish, thx for iOS answer. It is possible to package jar or aar from same kotlin native project?

Comment: @DixieFlatline, did you manage it? I'm trying to do the same and I'm a bit lost!